Какие тропы присутствуют в предложении «Сожгла себе всё лицо»?
Уважаемые!
У нас тут небольшой спор развязался, хотелось бы услышать мнение профессионала!
Кто-то упорно утверждает, что это метафора, кто-то, что это гипербола, кто-то просто называет переносным значением... Аргументы у всех, конечно, умопомрачительные, но хотелось бы узнать истину.
Сожгла себе всё лицо.
Употреблено в контексте описания события, в котором человек обжёг язык острым соусом.

Как язык на лицо влияет? Ладно бы речь шла о перцовом баллончике в глаза. Тогда бы можно было сказать, что "сжечь лицо" — метафора, (от др. -греч. μεταφορά — «перенос», «переносное значение») а "всё лицо" — гипербола (от др. -греч. ὑπερβολή «переход; чрезмерность, избыток; преувеличение»).

Выходит это ошибка? На самом деле спор об этом и был во многом. Правильное ли вообще предложение? Очень благодарны за ваш ответ!

смысловая ошибка, да.

А что человек хотел сказать, говоря, что обжёг всё лицо? Преувеличение, гипербола? Обжёг только рот и язык, а не всё лицо? Или речь о некой переносной вариации слова лицо - эмоциональные выражения. А слово "сжёг" может говорить не только о прямом огне, но и о химическом ожоге, а так же связанной с ним боли, покраснении и тп. Так что слово "обжёг" не ошибка.

Обжёг только язык и рот.

Понятно, но не понятно почему было сказано "лицо", как преувеличение или ещё в каком-то смысле? Но скорее всего "всё лицо" - гипербола, на этом всё. Сожгла, обжёг от ЖЕЧЬ: "3. кого-что. Палить, обжигать, сильно припекать. Пламя костра жжения. Крапива больно жжет. Горячий чай жжет горло. Ушаков." - то есть конечно не главное, но в полне распространённое употребление. И главное, другого слова, аналогичного, я не знаю. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/800062

Не совсем понятно, причем тут лицо, если  был обожжен язык.  Но даже и здесь, если действительно было обожжено лицо, здесь прямое значение слова. Никаких тропов здесь нет. О тропах ( гипербола) можно говорить, если степень  ожога явно  преувеличена.

лицо потому, что после употребления острого соуса оно становится краснючим, появляется кислая мина. Если мы хотим подчеркнуть этот факт, то "обжег язык" не слишком хорошо передает

Но это последствия, т.е. аллергия.
